# Integration test after deploy with fail-safe plugin

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, rest-assured, maven-failsafe-plugin

How would you run integration test separately after deploy is done.
In jenkins we will build, unit test, run some kind of embedded integration tests.

Then it will deploy to remote server.

How can I run Integration tests against remote deployed server? Running same fail-safe plugin will build the application again. The test will be rest-assured java based tests. How to invoke them without rebuilding the app?

Is the only way to somehow play with profiles? Profile for build and test and profile for black box integration(skiping unit tests and embedded integration test)

Maybe I can bind to maven validate phase, which will skip compilation with profile activating "black-box" fail-safe execution(for validation phase only)

Comment: I ended up using another failsafe plugin. Using separate profile. Was actually pain to set, but somehow is working unfortunatelly it runs also unit tests. And it was not failing even with errors until I have not set this property to build tab/advanced in jenkins job. `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false`